# How to make a custom pop up when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with a lot of buttons on it and I've made a custom popup that should popup in the center of the screen when a button is clicked. Ideally the screen darkens when the window comes up and you can click off anywhere on the screen to make the window go away.

How is this done? Below is a snippet of my buttons + the popup I'd like to display when a button is pressed. The CSS window has `display:hidden` at the moment however.

```js
var containerDiv = document.querySelector("#main");
let tempCounterBtn = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = "div-" + (i + 1);
  containerDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.id = "button-" + (tempCounterBtn + 1);
    tempCounterBtn++;
    newDiv.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1.2em;
}

button {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #a5afaa;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: .6em;
    padding: 3em;
}

button:hover {
    border-color: #fff8cc;
    box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0em yellow;
}

#main {
    border: solid 2px #939388;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #0f0f3de8;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
}


.smallFrame {
    display: none;
    border: solid 2px #939388;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #0f0f3de8;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="inner-15" class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="smallFrame"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changes

`div#main` has been changed to `dialog#main`. `<dialog>` is a built-in HTML tag and is normally hidden unless it has the `open` attribute or has been opened by one of it's methods either `.showModal()` or `.show()`. `.showModal()` is what you'd be interested in because there's a special CSS property that only applies to fullscreen backgrounds or a dialog's backdrop -- it's appropriately called `::backdrop` (see CSS of example).

Added 2 buttons one to close the `<dialog>` and another to open it.

Added a `flag` which is `true` to start out at then once the `<dialog>` opens that button generating function starts and then that flag is set to `false`. I had to stop it because I'm not sure if you wanted it to keep making buttons every time the `<dialog>` opens or not. Anyways, the `flag` is easily removed or you could adjust the conditions in which the `flag` is set to.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".smallFrame");
const show = document.querySelector('.show');
const hide = document.querySelector('.hide');

let flag = true;
show.onclick = popUp;
hide.onclick = e => modal.close();

function popUp(e) {
  modal.showModal();
 
  if (!flag) {
    return;
  }
  let tempCounterBtn = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "div-" + (i + 1);
    modal.appendChild(newDiv);
    for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.id = "button-" + (tempCounterBtn + 1);
      tempCounterBtn++;
      newDiv.appendChild(btn);
    }
  }
  flag = false;
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.25 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1.2em;
}

button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #a5afaa;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: .6em;
  padding: 3em;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #fff8cc;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0em yellow;
}

#main {
  border: solid 2px #939388;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #0f0f3de8;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#main::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.smallFrame {
  border: solid 2px #939388;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #0f0f3de8;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}

.hide {
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: right;
}

.show:hover,
.hide:hover {
  border-color: #fff8cc;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 1em 0em lime;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="inner-15" class="inner"></div>
</div>
<button class='show'>Show</button>

<dialog class="smallFrame">
  <button class='hide'>Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you! This isn't exactly what I was looking for but nonetheless I think your example should help me set this up. I wanted the buttons on `div#main` to display `div.smallFrame` when they are clicked.

Comment: So the `div.smallFrame` is the popup/dialog?

Comment: Yes! That's the popup

Comment: Ooops! I'll try to update the answer. Initially, I was confused because nothing on the page was visible.

Comment: Ok, `.smallFrame` is now the `<dialog>` and the `<button>`s are also in `.smallFrame` now.